# Regex for one character followed by - and a number

Tags: regex

I have a text field in a form. that field should only allow a user to enter number from 1 - 99 or T-1 to T-99 or U-1 to U-99 or T or U. I was able to figure out the pattern to allow numbers from 1-99.

Code I am using: `^(0?[1-9][1-9][0-9])$`

Could anyone please help. I am fairly new to the complex regex patterns.

Comment: Just a note... The regex you posted (`^(0?[1-9][1-9][0-9])$`) matches `0999` or `999`  but not `99`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following one should suit your needs:

```
^(?:(?:[TU]-)?[1-9][0-9]?|[TU])$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fZjdSZFBjtb3F4we)